# Linear Program Feasible

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the LP:

$
\max 0^T x\\
\mbox{subject to } Ax \leq b\\
$

Is this LP feasible or infeasible? I am unsure since I cannot prove it is infeasible although the objective value is always going to be $0$? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If the set $\{x~:~Ax\leq b\}$ is empty then the problem is infeasible, otherwise it is feasible with objective value $0$.